# Does a printer extension exist for php 5,6.8 or 7 for IIS?

Tags: php, printing

I currently have php 5.6.8 installed and would rather have php 7
I'm trying to:

1. get a list of network shared printers and
2. be able to print envelopes to any one of those printers.

I've  tried [a 5.6.8 windows provided version](https://github.com/gimjudge/php), but it doesn't work.
I have the php_printer.dll in the ext folder and
***extension=php_printer.dll*** in php.ini
No printer extension shows up with phpinfo()
Is there *any* way to access network printers with php 5.6.8 on an x64 Windows box using IIS?

Comment: If your php is x64, things won't work. Check attributes of what you have downloaded, because it may be x86 (is the architecture ussualy provided). Consider building it: It must not be hard on 5.6.8. php7 is a whole different story.